# Finding the Volume of a Truncated Pyramid with a Square base

Tags: calculus, area, volume

The question I am stuck on is asking to find the volume of a square frustum with has height $h$, upper side length $l$, and lower side length $k$. I have to solve it using a definite integral, so I can't create it into a full triangle and chop off the top using similar triangles; using geometry/similar triangles is kinda out.

This is what I have so far. I believe I need to take square cross section and the square formula would be $a(x)= f(x)^2$. However, I do not know how to figure out the height. If someone could help me out in the right direction that would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write down a linear expression, $f(x)$, such that $f(0)=k$ and $f(h)=l$? If you can do that, then you could integrate the square of $f(x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=h$.

Comment: Ya I believe I could do that! When I would integrate would I have to come up with a formula for f(x) such as the area?

Comment: If $f(x)$ gives you the edge length, then $f(x)^2$ gives you the area of the horizontal cross section.

Comment: So for f(x) could I do this b-x/h(b-a)?

Comment: Are you using $a$ and $b$ for $k$ and $l$? You just need a straight line that passes through the points $(0,k)$ and $(h,l)$.